# How would you display multiple fields on a node in d3?

Tags: d3.js, graph-visualization

I am new to d3 and I have objects that are connected to each other. Each of these objects has multiple fields that I want to display. I was wondering how can you do this in d3.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure I understand the question, but what I think you’re going for is something like this:

Make your selection and bind the data.

```
let update = d3.selectAll(".object").data(objects);
```

Remove old elements (if necessary).

```
update.exit().remove();
```

Create an `enter` selection and append a child for each field.

```
let enter = update.enter()
    .append("g").attr("class", "object");
enter.append("g").attr("class", "field1");
enter.append("g").attr("class", "field2");
```

Merge your `enter` selection back into `update`, then fill in the fields.

```
update = update.merge(enter);
update.select(".field1").text(d => d.field1);
update.select(".field2").text(d => d.field2);
```